# Trouble with axis gridlines

Tags: d3.js

could anyone give me any insight into how to accomplish the following: I am trying to create a very specific grid line with specific tick values and tick sizes on an axis. I am trying to accomplish the following: [image: End Goal]

[image][image: What I have so far]

No matter what I do, I cannot get the grid line to only appear within the boundary of the chart and not all the away across the axis under the tick values.

This is as close as I can get

[image]

I have tried every type of combination of axis types, scale types, widths, etc...i am a relative newbie. Additionally I need to have the y axis tick values be pre-set with different values [0,100,300, 750] but have the distance between the values be exactly the same.

````
```  this.yAxisGrid = d3_axisLeft(this.yScale)
        .tickSize(-this.dimensions.boundedWidth)
        .tickFormat("")
        .tickValues(null)
        .tickSizeInner(-this.dimensions.width)
        .tickPadding(4)
        .ticks(5);
```
````

I have also tried something like this.

````
```  svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis-grid")
        .call(
            this.make_y_gridlines()
                .tickSize(-this.dimensions.width, 0)
                .tickValues(null)
                .tickFormat("")
        );
```
````

Expected results are displayed in the image about

Comment: FYI. the x axis is a categorical scaleBand and the y is scaleLinear

Comment: Can you please put your code in a codesandbox or codepen? Would be happy to help you troubleshoot if you did that.

Comment: @CathyHa Hi, thank you for your offer. I am trying to do so now. It's part of an angular app in which the svg elements are angular components. I am trying to get a sample into code sandbox but it's not cooperating. I hope to get it in there or stackblitz this morning.